# Indent UITableViewCell and show Background of TableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, customization

Is there any way I can indent a tableview cell and be able to see the tableviews background?

```
------------
|normal     |
------------
xx|indented |
------------
|normal     |
-------------
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

That's kinda the effect I'm looking for. Where the x = the textured linen background apple provides.

Answer (score 0):

set the height for section say 39, then in vew for section make a view, set is's background color with clear color n return this view, tell me if this helps u

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I don't quite understand why I would set the height. What section are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is subclass UITableViewCell, with clearColor cells by default. Create your own content view layered ontop of the cells.

Create a `setIndented` method that applies the adjustment for the cells width and position. Now from your `cellForRowAtIndex` method you could do something like this, to the cell you want indented.

```
[cell setIndented];
```

Hope this helps, apologize for any typos as I did this from my phone. :)

you can try something like this for your indent method.

**UPDATE**: your setIndented method could look something like below. We set an indent padding, add it to the x axis because the width is subtracting the padding so the cell doesn't go out of the screen. This is untested, just theory.

```
int padding = 30;
[self.viewLayer setFrame:CGRect(self.viewLayer.frame.origin.x+padding,self.viewLayer.frame.origin.y,self.viewLayer.frame.width-padding,self.viewLayer.frame.height)];
```

Comment: Well I'm halfway there. I already use a custom cell. I'm just not clear what I would put I'n a setIndent method...

Comment: I think I understand. but viewLayer doesn't work. and Neither will contentview apparently because it doesn't have a width peoperty. I'm trying to modify a UIView right? Or a a CALayer?

Comment: I've tried this with [self.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x+padding, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, self.contentView.frame.size.width-padding, self.contentView.frame.size.height)]; and also window instead of contentview. Doesn't do anything.